# Intermittent Pg.dll crash on PostgreSQL 9.0.1 + ActivePerl 1007 + Apache 2.2.17 on Win2k3sp2

Tags: perl, apache, postgresql, dbi

We've been having mysterious, intermittent Apache crashes lately, a few times a day, but without pattern as to when or how long in between or what time of day.

I would upgrade DBD::Pg, but I couldn't find a PPD out there for anything newer than the one we use (2.14.1).  That said, the changes since then don't seem particularly relevant to our usage.

The Windows Event Viewer shows this:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Error
Event Category: (100)
Event ID:   1000
Date:       2010-11-01
Time:       9:55:28 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   myserver
Description:
Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.17.0, faulting module Pg.dll, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x0000e8a5.
```

So I looked in the Apache logs, which said:

```
[Mon Nov 01 09:55:32 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
```

Not terribly helpful, so I looked in the PostgreSQL logs (Pg.dll is part of `DBD::Pg`), and they said:

```
2010-11-01 09:55:32 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:32 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2010-11-01 09:55:33 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

But other than that I have no clue as to the cause, except possibly times of higher (but not that high--we have very few users) server load.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Similar to this report: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36728

Comment: I'm looking for ways to dig deeper in order to find out what the problem might be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intermittent networking problems may cause this.  I tried logging into PostgreSQL using psql from Turnkey running on VirtualBox on the same server PostgreSQL is running on, and it would sometimes cause PostgreSQL threads to take up a lot more CPU, and then not allow the login in the end.  Installing PostgreSQL on Turnkey made this stop happening, so it's possible that there's a general networking problem at the Windows level that is causing PostgreSQL and Pg.dll in particular to choke, which then crashes Apache, since DBD::Pg is loaded persistently via mod_perl.